# C# Removing all extra occurrences BEYOND the FIRST in string

Tags: c#, regex

So, I have some code that works the way I want it to, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this with a regex? I have played with a few regex but with no luck(And I know I need to get better with regex stuff).

This code is purely designed to remove any extra spaces or non email valid characters. Then it goes through and removes extra @ symbols beyond the first.

```
        List<string> second_pass = new List<string>();
        string final_pass = "";

        if (email_input.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            string first_pass = Regex.Replace(email_input.Text, @"[^\w\.@-]", "");

            if (first_pass.Contains("@"))
            {
                second_pass = first_pass.Split('@').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToList();

                string third_pass = second_pass[0] + "@" + second_pass[1];

                second_pass.Remove(second_pass[0]);
                second_pass.Remove(second_pass[1]);

                if (second_pass.Count > 0)
                {
                    final_pass = third_pass + string.Join("", second_pass.ToArray());
                }
            }

            email_output.Text = final_pass;
        }
```

Comment: Any clear examples of what is the current output, or what is going unexpectedly wrong with your current code?

Comment: @SWLim Nothing is wrong with the code, I am merely asking if there is a way to do with a regex instead of what I have.

Comment: Sorry I have misread your question

Comment: So, what are the requirements for a regex? Provide an input string and expected output.

Comment: Do you just want to remove all spaces and `@` after the first `@`?

Answer (score 1):

Going by your description and not the code:

```
var final_pass = email_input.Text;
var atPos = final_pass.IndexOf('@');
if (atPos++ >= 0)
    final_pass = final+pass.Substring(0, atPos) + Regex.Replace(final_pass.Substring(atPos), "[@ ]", "");
```

For an (almost) pure regex solution, using a state cheap, this seems to be working:

```
var first = 0;
final_pass = Regex.Replace(final_pass, "(^.+?@)?([^ @]+?)?[@ ]", m => (first++ == 0) ? m.Groups[1].Value+m.Groups[2].Value : m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: This works really well. I like the whole use of Substring. Was still hoping for a pure regex way to do it, but this is still really good. Thanks!

Comment: I added an example using only `Regex.Replace` and a state cheat.

Comment: I think I fixed the regex+state option.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get by by replacing only the captured groups, then this should be able to work.

`([^\w\.\@\-])|(?<=\@).*?(\@)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wrY6Hk/3)**

Comment: This looks pretty good, however it seems safer to just use substrings. I will definitely add this to my library though so thanks!